# Diffuse an animated SpriteKit Scene over an SCNPlane (ARKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

tl;dr I'm trying to animate an SKScene on a plane in ARKit (i.e. a table). I can get the SKScene to appear by texturing an SCNPlane with it, but it does not animate. How can I get the animations to work?

Hi,

I'm trying to make an ARKit game which is essentially just a 2D game rendered on a plane anchored in the 3D world. I have the game as an SKScene object. Usually when rendering an SKScene in ARKit I'll create an SCNPlane and set the material to be an SCNMaterial with the SKScene diffused. This is what my current code looks like (in my `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)`:

```
    guard let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") else { return }

    let scnMaterial = SCNMaterial()

    scnMaterial.diffuse.contents = scene

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.8, height: 0.6)

    plane.firstMaterial = scnMaterial

    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
```

This renders the SKScene fine, but the `update(_:)` function is never called. After some research, I found out that when diffusing an SKScene onto an SCNMaterial, it pauses the scene. So, I added `self.isPaused = false` to the `sceneDidLoad()` of the SKScene. This gets the `update(_:)` function to run, but the texture on the SCNPlane is never updated, so the SKScene maintains its starting look. When the SKScene is run on its own in a UIViewController it works fine.

Does anyone know how I can get an animated SKScene to animate on an SCNPlane? At the end of the day, I just want an SKScene to animate on a plane (i.e. a table) in ARKit, so any alternative methods would work.

Answer (score 0):

A Scenekit view runs its own rendering loop
and it does not update/render those node who are not moving by actions or physics movement.

Scenekit automatically decides when to update/render the nodes and when to not.

Try to apply continuous SCNAction or CAAnimation to your SCNPlane node with some movement, and it the diffuse property animation should work.